# Label observations via ranking on multiple columns, taking ties into account

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe looking like:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   group name    sum count max_elements
   <int> <fct> <int> <int>        <int>
 1     1 aaa       3     2            4
 2     1 bbb       3     1            4
 3     1 ccc       2     2            4
 4     1 ddd       2     2            4
 5     1 eee       1     0            4
 6     2 aaa       3     2            3
 7     2 bbb       3     1            3
 8     2 ccc       2     3            3
 9     2 ddd       2     1            3
10     3 aaa       3     4            4
11     3 bbb       3     2            4
12     3 ccc       2     5            4
13     3 ddd       2     1            4
14     3 eee       2     1            4
15     3 fff       2     1            4
```

I would like to label each observation following this decision reasoning:

- order by group all names first by sum and then by count
- for each group consider the max_elements value
- for each name, create a label as:

  - `selected`, if the name has high sum and high count within the max nth element threshold.
  - `pick_random`, if several names have same sum and same count within the max nth element threshold.
  - `not_selected`, if it is outside of the 'race'

For example for `group 1`, the result would like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  group name  decision      sum count max_elements
  <int> <fct> <fct>       <int> <int>        <int>
1     1 aaa   selected        3     2            4
2     1 bbb   selected        3     1            4
3     1 ccc   pick_random     2     2            4
4     1 ddd   pick_random     2     2            4
5     1 eee   selected        1     0            4
```

For `group 2`, there is no random selection, since all names score without ties within the max size.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  group name  decision       sum count max_elements
  <int> <fct> <fct>        <int> <int>        <int>
1     2 aaa   selected         3     2            3
2     2 bbb   selected         3     1            3
3     2 ccc   selected         2     3            3
4     2 ddd   not_selected     2     1            3
```

For `group 3` instead:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  group name  decision          sum count max_elements
  <int> <fct> <fct>           <int> <int>        <int>
1     3 aaa   selected            3     4            4
2     3 bbb   selected            3     2            4
3     3 ccc   selected            2     5            4
4     3 ddd   pick_random         2     1            4
5     3 eee   pick_random         2     1            4
6     3 fff   pick_random         2     1            4
```

The final output df will look like:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 6
   group name  decision          sum count max_elements
   <int> <fct> <fct>           <int> <int>        <int>
 1     1 aaa   selected            3     2            4
 2     1 bbb   selected            3     1            4
 3     1 ccc   pick_random         2     2            4
 4     1 ddd   pick_random         2     2            4
 5     1 eee   selected            1     0            4
 6     2 aaa   selected            3     2            3
 7     2 bbb   selected            3     1            3
 8     2 ccc   selected            2     3            3
 9     2 ddd   not_selected        2     1            3
10     3 aaa   selected            3     4            4
11     3 bbb   selected            3     2            4
12     3 ccc   selected            2     5            4
13     3 ddd   pick_random         2     1            4
14     3 eee   pick_random         2     1            4
15     3 fff   pick_random         2     1            4
```

Reproducible df:

```
structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", 
"ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff"), class = "factor"), sum = c(3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), count = c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L), max_elements = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So far I tried to arrange and use top_n.
But I can't figure out how to label cases in which multiple observations have same count and same sum.

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(-sum, -count) %>%
  top_n(as.integer(max_elements))
```

Comment: I am sorry, updated with a clearer dataset structure. @Salman

Comment: can you please somehow explain again how these decision rules work. e.g. why is ddd in group 2 "not selected" or oder ddd in group 3 "pick one random" - which was not explained (cave: "pick random"). furthermore, can you provide the code that you already written, so we get a guess?

Comment: Edited all labels to "pick_random". 'ddd' in group 2 is not selected because for that group the max size of elements to pick up is "3". @Stephan

Comment: edited example with top_n and edited the title for clarity @Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt to solve your question. We can use `rleid` from the `data.table` package to create the `Rank` column. After that, we can use `case_when` to assign the label based on the conditions. Notice that it is important to arrange the columns for the right order before applying this. It seems like you have done this already. If not, add `arrange(group, name, sum, count)` as the first pipe operation.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(group, sum, count) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(Rank = rleid(sum, count)) %>%
  mutate(decision = case_when(
    n > 1 & Rank <= max_elements   ~ "pick_random",
    Rank > max_elements            ~ "not_selected",
    TRUE                           ~ "selected",
  )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(group, name, decision, sum, count, max_elements) %>%
  mutate(decision = factor(decision))
dat2
# # A tibble: 15 x 6
#    group name  decision       sum count max_elements
#    <int> <fct> <fct>        <int> <int>        <int>
#  1     1 aaa   selected         3     2            4
#  2     1 bbb   selected         3     1            4
#  3     1 ccc   pick_random      2     2            4
#  4     1 ddd   pick_random      2     2            4
#  5     1 eee   selected         1     0            4
#  6     2 aaa   selected         3     2            3
#  7     2 bbb   selected         3     1            3
#  8     2 ccc   selected         2     3            3
#  9     2 ddd   not_selected     2     1            3
# 10     3 aaa   selected         3     4            4
# 11     3 bbb   selected         3     2            4
# 12     3 ccc   selected         2     5            4
# 13     3 ddd   pick_random      2     1            4
# 14     3 eee   pick_random      2     1            4
# 15     3 fff   pick_random      2     1            4
```

Comment: Hey, great! I think I might go in the right direction. I explain you the logic in detail. Let's take group 1, I have 5 elements and I have to pick up 4 (the max_elements value). I rank them first with sum, then with priority. aaa and bbb are the top 2. ccc and ddd have the same values for sum count - i pick just ONE of the two, but label them as "pick_random", then eee is the last after them to be picked: the final size of the group is gonna be 4. Does it clarify? @www

Comment: @thequietus Thanks for your explanation. Please see my update to see if this makes sense.

Comment: it works! amazing. took a while because I forgot to explicitly add the arrange in the first pipe operator.